# window.height() in Chrome changes after first loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, css

I'm building a page that depends on the height of the window, but on Chrome this value is different when I first load the page after opening the browser, it's about 60 pixels smaller, thus leaving a blank section on the bottom of the page. When I reload the page, everything goes ok.

I logged the dimension of the page before and after I load the plugin (which builds the page), using a 1920x1080 screen. First time, before loading the plugin the window is 923px tall, after it becomes 906px (I assume those 17px of difference are here due to a slidebar, since it happens the same thing for the width). If I reload, the page goes from 979px of height to 962px.

Can someone explain me why this happens? I load the plugin with `$(window).ready()`, so I think that when I build the page everything is in its final state. I cannot test it on other browsers because it's written exclusively for Chrome and there's a lot of code which doesn't run on Firefox, IE or Opera (I tried, of course ^_^)

Comment: Are you adding any element dynamically in `ready()`? or just getting the height?

Comment: try using $(document).ready as this will wait for your page to load before it runs your plugin

Comment: or `$(window).load()` triggered after images are loaded

Comment: @Салман : I load everything in `ready()`, but the first thing I execute is `console.log($(window).height())` and I'm not changing the window size inside the code

Comment: @Pete : I tried also with `$(document).ready()` but it happens the same thing

Comment: @mikakun : I'm not loading images (but I'm loading a video), anyway I also tried `.load()` without success...

Comment: your actual plugin must be inserting new code into the window and changing the height although it sounds like it is trying to load something on first load that gets cached when you refresh the page (thus it working second time around)

Comment: Update: If I call my plugin after a timeout, everything looks fine. Maybe I'm getting the height of the window when the window hasn't ended its rendering yet. If someone can confirm that this is a real possibility, I can close the question ^_^